# Stamp on Amendment page

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have a valid visa to work here in UK. I went for a holiday in Paris for like 6 days. Upon returning in UK during the immigration check the IO stamped something on my passport particularly on the amendment page. I ignored it initially until I realized why IO should have stamped on that page knowing that there are plenty of pages available. By the way I am a Philippines passport holder.

[image]

Questions:

1. What is the relevance/indication of having this stamp on my passport?
2. will this stamp affect future travel?
3. Is there something I should be worried about?

Thank  you in advance

Comment: Is that the only stamp you received on that day?  Do the other UK stamps in your passport look different?

Comment: Yes. That’s was the only stamp I have got

Comment: The written number is that of your Biometric Residence Permit (BRP). As others have said, the officer didn't check what page he was stamping, but it won't cause you problems.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what specifically the RU number indicates, but

1. The stamp means that you were admitted to the UK at Heathrow airport on the 19th of December.
2. No
3. No

It's not at all uncommon for officers to find the blank "endorsements" or "amendments" page when they're looking for a blank "visas" page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worries me a lot. But why on this amendment page?

Comment: @Unknown Because the officer is lazy and it doesn't really matter, endorsement/amendment pages are very rarely used these days.